# Typescript: Generic type that extends a generic type on another class

Tags: typescript

Example

```
class BaseOptions {
    a: 1;
}

class OptionsA extends BaseOptions {
    b: 2;
}

class OptionsB extends BaseOptions {
    c: 3;
}

class Child<TOptions extends BaseOptions> {
    options: TOptions;
}

// Parent must use a child that supports TOptions
class Parent<TOptions extends BaseOptions, TChild extends Child<TOptions>> { }

// Supports OptionsA
class StrictChild extends Child<OptionsA> { }
// Supports OptionsA and OptionsB
class FlexibleChild extends Child<OptionsA | OptionsB> {
    doSomething() {
        if (this.options instanceof OptionsA) {
            const test1 = this.options.b;
        }
        // This should fail because no instanceof check
        const test2 = this.options.c;
    }
}

// Expected to fail because StrictChild can't have OptionsB
const parentA = new Parent<OptionsB, StrictChild>();
// Expected to pass because FlexibleChild can have OptionsA or OptionsB
// but fails because "OptionsA" is not assignable to "OptionsA | OptionsB"
const parentB = new Parent<OptionsB, FlexibleChild>();
```

I think the problem is

```
class Parent<TOptions extends BaseOptions, TChild extends Child<TOptions>> { }
```

specifically `Child<TOptions>` because I think it needs to be something like `Child<TOptions extends Child<T>>` but I have no idea how to do that.

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OptionsA%20extends%20BaseOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OptionsB%20extends%20BaseOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%203%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%3CTOptions%20extends%20BaseOptions%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20TOptions%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Parent%20must%20use%20a%20child%20that%20supports%20TOptions%0D%0Aclass%20Parent%3CTOptions%20extends%20BaseOptions%2C%20TChild%20extends%20Child%3CTOptions%3E%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Supports%20OptionsA%0D%0Aclass%20StrictChild%20extends%20Child%3COptionsA%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Supports%20OptionsA%20and%20OptionsB%0D%0Aclass%20FlexibleChild%20extends%20Child%3COptionsA%20%7C%20OptionsB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.options%20instanceof%20OptionsA)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20test1%20%3D%20this.options.b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20should%20fail%20because%20not%20instanceof%20check%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20test2%20%3D%20this.options.c%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20fail%20because%20StrictChild%20can't%20have%20OptionsB%0D%0Aconst%20parentA%20%3D%20new%20Parent%3COptionsB%2C%20StrictChild%3E()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20pass%20because%20FlexibleChild%20can%20have%20OptionsA%20or%20OptionsB%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20fails%20because%20%22OptionsA%22%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20%22OptionsA%20%7C%20OptionsB%22%0D%0Aconst%20parentB%20%3D%20new%20Parent%3COptionsB%2C%20FlexibleChild%3E()%3B)

Comment: Isn't this behaving as expected? `OptionsA | OptionsB` means that a child could have an `options` property that's `OptionsA` and, therefore, not compatible with the `OptionsB` in `Parent<OptionsB, FlexibleChild>`. Wouldn't a flexible child be `FlexibleChild extends Child<OptionsA & OptionsB>`? That is, at the moment, `FlexibleChild` is more of an unknown child and that's the problem - TypeScript doesn't know if `options` is `OptionsB` or not.

Comment: @cartant Hmm I don't think that is quite right, if you use & then you can use `this.options.b` and `this.options.c` without checking that they exist. The intention is that `FlexibleChild` supports OptionsA OR OptionsB but not both at once.

Comment: My example probably makes more sense if OptionsA is a class so you can check instanceof

Comment: If that's the case, the error is entirely appropriate and you cannot do what you want. You'd have to use something like `const parentAorB = new Parent<OptionsA | OptionsB, FlexibleChild>();` as there is no guarantee that the child has an `options` property that's `OptionsB`.

Comment: But can't we guarantee that by passing FlexibleChild which does allow  OptionsB? Maybe I am structuring this wrong. Parent will receive the options object and then create a FlexibleChild instance with the options object.I just want to check that the options class and child class passed to Parent are compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it working so long as I set a default generic on Child so that I can use TChild['options']

```
class Child<TOptions extends BaseOptions = BaseOptions> {
    options: TOptions;
}

// Parent must use a child that supports TOptions
class Parent<TOptions extends TChild['options'], TChild extends Child> { }
```

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OptionsA%20extends%20BaseOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OptionsB%20extends%20BaseOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%203%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%3CTOptions%20extends%20BaseOptions%20%3D%20BaseOptions%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20TOptions%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Parent%20must%20use%20a%20child%20that%20supports%20TOptions%0D%0Aclass%20Parent%3CTOptions%20extends%20TChild%5B'options'%5D%2C%20TChild%20extends%20Child%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Supports%20OptionsA%0D%0Aclass%20StrictChild%20extends%20Child%3COptionsA%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Supports%20OptionsA%20and%20OptionsB%0D%0Aclass%20FlexibleChild%20extends%20Child%3COptionsA%20%7C%20OptionsB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.options%20instanceof%20OptionsA)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20test1%20%3D%20this.options.b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20should%20fail%20because%20not%20instanceof%20check%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20test2%20%3D%20this.options.c%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20fail%20because%20StrictChild%20can't%20have%20OptionsB%0D%0Aclass%20ParentA%20extends%20Parent%3COptionsB%2C%20StrictChild%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20pass%20because%20FlexibleChild%20can%20have%20OptionsA%20or%20OptionsB%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20fails%20because%20%22OptionsA%22%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20%22OptionsA%20%7C%20OptionsB%22%0D%0Aclass%20ParentB%20extends%20Parent%3COptionsB%2C%20FlexibleChild%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A)

**Edit**

Alternatively you can just do

```
class Parent<TOptions extends TChild['options'], TChild extends Child<BaseOptions>> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **intersection types**, not union types!

```
// Supports OptionsA and OptionsB
class FlexibleChild extends Child<OptionsA & OptionsB> { }
```

Now this is a perfectly valid statement:

```
const parentB = new Parent<OptionsB, FlexibleChild>();
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

> An intersection type combines multiple types into one. This allows you to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the features you need. For example, `Person & Serializable & Loggable` is a `Person` and `Serializable` and `Loggable`. That means an object of this type will have all members of all three types.

Comment: I think this is close but see my comment on the question.